# How to change navbar colour after scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to chnage the colour of my navbar from transparent to black after the user scrolls down. However, my javascript does not seem to work as nothing happens. I have looked at several videos and similar questions and none have worked

HTML

```html
<nav role='navigation' class="sticky-top bg-transparent">
      <img class="navbar-brand" src="../static/website_Images/logo.jpg" alt="Logo" style="height:90px;">
      <div id="menuToggle">
        <input type="checkbox" />
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          <ul id="menu">
            <a href="/"><li>Home</li></a>
            <a href="/image_submit"><li>Submit Image</li></a>
            <a href="/image_search"><li>Search Image</li></a>
            <a href="/login"><li>Login/Sign up</li></a>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

JS

```
<script >
    $(window).scroll(function(){
     $('nav').toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > 100);
     });
    </script>
```

CSS

```
.bg-transparent{
  height: 90px;
  }

.bg-transparent.scrolled{
  background: black !important;
}
```

Comment: Share some code? Check out codepen.io or codesandbox.io

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript code is incorrect.
Test with this code :

```
  window.onscroll = function () { scrollHeaderHandler() };

  function scrollHeaderHandler() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {
      $('nav').addClass('scrolled');
    } else {
      $('nav').removeClass('scrolled');
    }
  }
```